# Where to put Assets in Symfony Application and how to work in a development environment

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm currently playing with assetic and symfony. I use compression and rewrite, and I decided to put my assets (mainly javascript files and css files) in bundle as it seems to be the best practice **(Confirmation would be appreciated)**.

In a development environment, this work with some configuration, but I can't figure out how to generate compiled assets.

I want to be able to modify my assets directly in the `src/domain_name/bundle_name/Resources/public/css` or `src/domain_name/bundle_name/Resources/public/javascript`, and that those modificaiton could be checked right away in the development environment.

I use the command `php app/console assetic:dump --watch`, but it seems it only checked the generated files in the `web/bundle/` directory.

So i need to keep running the command `php app/console assets:install web` to copy over and over the assets.

In fact this seems to be a consequence of the issue that assetic can't work with bundle notation [(See last comment of kriss wallsmith here)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-devs/5JOZCBrtW4w). If I was able to use that bundle notation, I guess the watch command would be able to automatically upgrade assets in the web directory, but not sure about that.

**How I reference assets in twig templates**

```
{% stylesheets filter='?yui_css,cssrewrite' output='css/compiled/fullapplication.css'
    'bundles/bundle_name/third-party/jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css'
    'bundles/bundle_name/third-party/jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery.mobile.libri.theme.css'
    'bundles/bundle_name/third-party/jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.css'
    'bundles/bundle_name/css/global.css'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts filter='?yui_js' output='js/compiled/fullapplication.js'
    'bundles/bundle_name/third-party/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" >
{% endjavascripts %}
```

**Any idea how to be more efficient while working on assets in a development environment ? Shall we wait for the bundle notation feature in assetic ?**

Answer (score 0):

Put JS,CSS and so, directly into bundle, is a good practice since they're used only into that bundle. If you have more general ones, maybe is better to put them in a more general environment (app?)
If you want to avoid copying assets over and over again, you coul use the `--symlink` option (`php app/console assets:install web --symlink`).
In that way every change into `assets`, **if not** cached, is directly available to app.

For notation, you can directly reference them by they're symlink for avoid bundle's notation.